# INDEX REBUILD IMPACT ON sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

Tags: sql-server

In which case (or sql versions) are the index statistics reset by index rebuild?
There are a lot of articles which makes me think that perhaps this behavior wasn’t always the case.

Answer (score 7):

Kendra Little breaks this down in detail on her blog here: [Index Usage Stats Bug Fixed in SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU12 / SP3 CU3](https://littlekendra.com/2016/05/18/index-usage-stats-bug-fixed-in-sql-server-2012-sp2-cu12-sp3-cu3/)

I've quoted the table from that blog post below:

> | SQL Server Version | sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats | Missing Index DMVs |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | SQL Server 2005 & SQL Server 2008R2 | Reset on database offline/restart. | Reset on any index drop/disable/create on that table. Reset on database offline/restart. |
> | SQL Server 2012 | Reset on ALTER INDEX REBUILD of that index until SP2+CU12 or SP3+CU3 . Reset on database offline/restart. | Reset on any index drop/disable/create on that table. Reset on database offline/restart. Reset on ALTER INDEX REBUILD of any index on the table. |
> | SQL Server 2014 | Reset on ALTER INDEX REBUILD of that index until SP2. Reset on database offline/restart. | Reset on any index drop/disable/create on that table. Reset on database offline/restart. Reset on ALTER INDEX REBUILD of any index on the table. |
> | SQL Server 2016 | Reset on database offline/restart. | Reset on any index drop/disable/create on that table. Reset on database offline/restart. Reset on ALTER INDEX REBUILD of any index on the table. |

The gist of it is that these stats got reset on index rebuilds in certain builds of SQL Server 2012 and 2014.  You should update to the latest SP / CU, or to SQL Server 2016 or higher, to avoid the problem.